# How do I run an app on a real iOS device using Expo?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I am using Expo to run my application. I am able to see two options in Expo XDE:

1. open on iOS simulator
2. open on Android
   [image: XDE]

I want to run my app by directly connecting to my device. Is it possible with Expo?

Comment: Did my answer work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and quite easy to get it running.

**Step 1:** Open Expo XDE, and click on the gray cog to change host mode to LAN. Make sure you enabled Development Mode. You'll see an URL right in front of you. Wait until packager to start running.

[image: computer]

**Step 2:** Open Expo App in your mobile device, and click on the second tab '**Explore**' and enter the URL that starts with `exp://192.168...` This is a local connection to your computer. You will see your app running in a minute.

**Make sure your phone and computer are on the same WiFi!**

For further information, you may refer to official documents [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v16.0.0/guides/debugging.html).

[image]

Comment: 'Explore'  tab doesn't exist anymore, would you mind updating your answer accordingly ?

Comment: Thanks Raptor, I wasn’t able to access my computer and update the answer

Comment: You have to open the link over Safari on your mobile device :) it will launch expo.

Comment: Is there no way to get a `.ipa` or use the `tar.gz` generated with `expo build:ios -t simulator` and install it on the device ? Please confirm if we can just use `exp://`  or if we can install the app and get the icon like does the app on the iOS simulator when it start.

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking to [run a native build](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/run-on-device/#running-a-project-with-a-development-build) without using `Expo Go` on a physical iOS device (not a simulator), you can plug in your device to your computer by cable and use the following code:

```
npx expo run:ios --device
```

This is useful in cases when you need to test notifications, native code, etc.

Comment: My application is stuck at building 100% and if I closed the app and opened it again  it still stuck on loading from metro

Comment: Oof that's not fun... A few things I generally do:
1) Make sure the phone and laptop are on same WiFi network
2) Delete the test app and re-run the command
3) Try `rm -rf ios && npx expo prebuild` which will delete the existing iOS files and regenerate them from scratch

Comment: I installed a new expo app using this command `npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject` and then ran this command `npx expo run:ios --device` the application eventually run on my device but it took for ever like more than 4hrs to load on my iphone (iphone 11, ios 16) so I think there must be something wrong here. It should run right away, just like in android, when I used `expo run:android --device`, the app worked immediatly without any further delay. but on ios it keep loading bundle for ever and eventually it loads it. every time I run the command, not just the first time

Answer (score 14):

As the Expo Client App is updated due to new Apple's approval requirements, please follow the steps below to launch the App in a real iOS device:

1. Connect both your computer and your iOS device with same Wi-Fi
2. In Expo XDE, select Host > LAN (please refer to eden's answer)
3. Open MobileSafari in your iOS device. Type the URL shown in Expo XDE (should be something like exp://192.168.123.123:19000). Alternatively, you can click "Share" button in Expo XDE to show a QR Code. Use Camera App in iOS (iOS 11+) or any QR code reader (iOS 9 & 10) to scan the QR Code.
4. MobileSafari, or your QR code reader / Camera App, will ask if you want to launch the App in Expo Client App, select "Yes"
5. Your project will be loaded accordingly.

Hope it helps.

[image: Screenshot for Step 3]

Comment: Is there no way to get a `.ipa` or use the `tar.gz` generated with `expo build:ios -t simulator` and install it on the device ? Please confirm if we can just use `exp://`  or if we can install the app and get the icon like does the app on the iOS simulator when it start.

Comment: Be aware that many things do not quite work the same way when running in the Expo app on iOS and Android. This approach is okay for rapid prototyping, but it is not a replacement for testing your app natively on your device.